# Hint to finding $\int_{0}^{100} (x-\lfloor x\rfloor).\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

Wolfram Alpha gives it to be 50, and I seem to find no way to the solution. 
$$\int_{0}^{100} (x-\lfloor x\rfloor).\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: When in doubt, draw a diagram

Answer (score 8):

Hint: Write it as $\sum_{i=0}^{99} \int_{i}^{i+1} (x-i)\,dx$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

$\lfloor x+1\rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor+1$, hence the function $\,x\mapsto x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is periodic.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing the typo.

Comment: This answer is definitely better than mine :)

Comment: Actually, it's virtually the same. The difference is only  I suppose known a general theorem that does the job.

Comment: Yeah, but mine requires more work to see it is $100\int_{0}^1 f(x)\,dx$. Noting it is periodic is clearer. My technique is, however, better for non-periodic examples, like $x^2-\lfloor x\rfloor^2$ and $x^2-\lfloor x^2\rfloor$. Yours cuts to the case for this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the areas under the graph of the function $f(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$. Specifically the rectangles/geometrical objects you can form and then form a sum to evaluate the area.

Answer (score 1):

Since function is periodic we get,
Integration of x - [x] from 0 to 100 
= Integration of {x} from 0 to 100
= 100 times of integration of x from 0 to 1
= 100 times (x^2)/2 from 0 to 1
= 100 times 1/2
= 50

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is the same thing as the *fractional/decimal part of $x$*. As in, the fractional part of $7.5$ is $0.5$. This also means that the function is periodic!